# Random Quote Generator

Tags: javascript

I have just created a random quote generator just as a form of practice.  Everything works fine, but I have one problem that's bugging me:

```
 var quotes = [(insert a bunch of quotes here) ];

 var length = quotes.length;
 var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(length - 1));

function showQuote(){document.write(quotes[rand]);}
showQuote();
```

Why does it only print when the document.write call is part of a function and not on it's own?

Comment: you need some way to output the text into the browser - rather than using document.write, why not put the text in an element and append the element to the document?

Comment: `document.write` works fine outside of a function....

Comment: For me, it [prints on its own](http://jsbin.com/iyerav/1/edit) without the need of wrapping into a function.

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong now.  I originally had a problem with my random number generator, but after I copied/pasted it from somewhere else, it worked.

Comment: How does that tell you what you did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `write()` inside the `body` tag:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var quotes = ['s', 'e', 's', 'e' ];

  var length = quotes.length;
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(length - 1));

  document.write(quotes[rand]);
</script>

</body></html>
```